# Why am I getting an encoding error with vpim in rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vcf-vcard

I get the following error:

```
Vpim::InvalidEncodingError (email@email.net):
2011-06-07T01:37:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/vpim-0.695/lib/vpim/field.rb:110:in `decode0'
```

It has worked fine for other vcards.  And the data looks right -- it should be an email:

Here is a sample vcard that blows up when there's an email...what I"ve done to fix it is manually remove the second email, but that's a pain:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Roberts;Paul;;;
FN:Paul Roberts
ORG:Sonoma Technology Inc
TITLE:EVP Business Dev/Chief Scientific Officer
TEL;WORK;VOICE:707-665-9900
TEL;WORK;FAX:707-665-9800
ADR;WORK;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:;;1455 N McDowell Blvd Suite D;Petaluma;CA;94954;USA
LABEL;WORK;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:1455 N McDowell Blvd Suite D=0D=0APetaluma, CA 94954=0D=0AUSA
URL:http://www.sonomatech.com
URL:http://www.sonomatech.com
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:paul@sonomatech.com
paul@sonomatech.com
NOTE;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=0D=0A Data provided by Lead411,  http://www.lead411.com/=0D=0A =0D=0A
END:VCARD
```

Here's my controller using paperclip and vpim:

```
 68      unless @contact.vcard.path.blank?
 69 
 70        paperclip_vcard = File.new(@contact.vcard.path)
 71 
 72       # try to scrub the vcard
 73        scrub_vcf(paperclip_vcard)
 74 
 75        @vcard = Vpim::Vcard.decode(paperclip_vcard).first
 76        @contact.title = @vcard.title
 77        @contact.email = @vcard.email
 78        @contact.first_name = @vcard.name.given
 79        @contact.last_name = @vcard.name.family
 80        @contact.phone = @vcard.telephones[0]
 81        @contact.fax = @vcard.telephones[1]
 82 
 83        @contact.address.street1 = @vcard.address.street
 84        @contact.address.city = @vcard.address.locality
 85        @contact.address.state = @vcard.address.region
 86        @contact.address.zip = @vcard.address.postalcode
 87        @contact.company_name = @vcard.org.fetch(0)
 88 
 89     end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at how your Vcards are being created; the second email on line 14 isn't a valid property definition, which is what's causing the parser to screw up (and which is why it parses successfully if you manually delete it).

You can read about the property definition in Section 2 in [the Vcard 2.1 specification](http://www.imc.org/pdi/vcard-21.txt) (the RTF version–which is far more readable–is available [here](http://www.imc.org/pdi/vcard-21.rtf)).

From the information you provided, this doesn't look like a problem with [Vpim](http://vpim.rubyforge.org/) on the decoding side, but rather how your Vcards are created. If you're creating the Vcards yourself, I'd take a look at your encoding logic. If you're receiving them from outside sources, then you might want to write some custom scrubbing logic to get rid of improper property definitions, so you don't have to manually remove them yourself.

You should be able to do this quite easily with a quick regex check on each line:

```
def scrub_vcf(vcard)
  line_arr = File.readlines(vcard)
  line_arr.delete_if { |line| line.match(/^.+\:.+$/).nil? }
  File.open(vcard, "w") do |f| 
    line_arr.each{|line| f.puts(line)}
  end
end
# use the scrubbed vcf with vpim
```

Of course, it would probably be quicker to keep this in an array rather than writing it back out to a file, FYI.

Hope that helps.

---

**UPDATE:** If you don't want to keep the file, you can return a string, which [Vpim can decode](http://vpim.rubyforge.org/classes/Vpim/Vcard.html#M000188) instead of a file:

```
def scrub_vcf(vcard)
  line_arr = File.readlines(vcard)
  line_arr.delete_if { |line| line.match(/^.+\:.+$/).nil? }
  return line_arr.join
end
# use the scrubbed vcf with vpim #=> Vpim::Vcard.decode(scrub_vcf(vcard))
```

Note that I ran into problems with using a String with `Vpim::Vcard.decode` when running ruby 1.9.x, due to the fact that the `String` class no longer has an `each` method. Ruby 1.8.7 works fine, though. Vpim looks like it hasn't been upgraded since 2008/2009, so it's probably not been upgraded for use with ruby 1.9.x.

---

**UPDATE AGAIN:** Here's a version of Vpim updated for use with ruby 1.9.x (fixes precisely the issue I ran into earlier): https://github.com/sam-github/vpim

Comment: @neezer, this should still work writing it back to the file on heroku, right?  Where should I put this method, in the controller where I am processing the vcf with vpim?

Comment: @Angela It depends if you want to keep a copy of the scrubbed vcard for use later. If so, then you can use [Amazon S3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) to store the copy, as Heroku's file system is read-only. If you don't need it later, just write the array back to a string, then use vpim on the string.

Comment: @Angela As for where to put this, again it depends on what you're doing with your code. Convention is "Fat Models, Skinny Controllers", so if your importing these vcards to your database, you might want to look into putting this in your model--perhaps in a `before_save` callback--to keep your controllers lean and mean.

Comment: @neezzer, thanks -- your code writes to the file, not the string, right?  I don't need to keep the scrubbed vcard....basically this scrubed it if there isn't a ":" character?

Comment: @neezer, yes...would prefer to put it in the model, right now my controller is fat and will refactor later, but just want to get this patched in teh short term -- I put it as a controller method but getting an error, I'll post my code, maybe you can suggest?

Comment: @Neezer -- I get a typeerror, can't convert file to string at the readlines command

Comment: @Angela - You're trying to scrub an empty file. Use `File.open` instead of `File.new` and see if that works. The regex checks for at least 1 character before a `:` (part of the specification mentioned earlier)--it's a quick and dirty way to scrub out values like that errant email address, but is by no means comprehensive.

Comment: @Angela - See my edit about using a string instead of a file.

Comment: @neezer, thanks --- btw, any thoughts on difference between vpim and there's a vcard gem?

Comment: @Angela - Looks like the vcard gem is simply the vcard module extracted straight from vpim: http://rubygems.org/gems/vcard If all you're doing is vcard processing, it might be a lighter to use the vcard gem instead of the whole vpim library.